# ¿Un sistema operativo multitarea tiene que ser también multiproceso?

Tags: hilos, proceso, multitasking

Entiendo que un sistema operativo multitarea tiene que ser a la fuerza multiproceso, pero no lo entiendo. Si alguien me lo confirmara y me lo explicara, se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

**El concepto de multitarea** se entiende mejor comparando el antiguo multitarea cooperativo (windows 3.1) vs el multitarea de windows 95.

En Windows 3.1, si ejecutabas dos programas a la vez (ej, word y excel), estas tareas manejaban una cola de comunicación con el CPU que permitía saber si otro programa estaba también participando en la demanda de recursos. En la medida que las llamadas al CPU y respuestas de éste se iban sucediendo, el primer programa pasaba el control al segundo y así sucesivamente. En el fondo, el CPU atendía un programa a la vez pero los programas cooperaban entre sí para soltar el CPU cuando no estaban ejecutando operaciones. Como este flujo de llamadas y respuestas no siempre era tan fluido e inmediado como en el caso ideal, en realidad para el usuario se sentía como si sólo corriera un programa a la vez.

Cuando salió Windows 95 una de sus grandes novedades fue el multitasking (multitarea) un entorno en donde el software no accede directamente a recursos de hardware, sino que el sistema operativo le asigna un sandbox para correr. De esa manera si corrías excel y word, no ocurría que excel se adueñara del CPU y tuvieras que esperar a que lo soltara. Ambos procesos corrían en sandboxes separados, y el sistema operativo era el intermediario entre éstos y los recursos de hardware, permitiendo cambiar entre uno y otro en microsegundos y brindando la sensación de que ambos corrían a la vez sin estorbarse.

**El concepto de multiproceso** se refiere a que un sistema operativo sea capaz de manejar más de un procesador, y en esto hay varios enfoques. Los servidores de los años 90 tenían varios CPU físicos. Mirabas la placa madre y había cuatro sockets para procesadores.

Esto evolucionó en el tiempo con la llegada de los procesadores multinúcleo (AMD Opteron primero, Intel Pentium D unos meses después) que en un solo procesador físico alojaban dos o más núcleos.

Entre medio, también Intel presentó una arquitectura llamada Hyperthreading que en un procesador de un solo núcleo creaba dos CPU virtuales (aunque era como un multinúcleo falso, en definitiva).

En definitiva, un OS multiproceso permite que cuando abras word y excel sus respectivos sandboxes se asignen a diferentes núcleos físicos. Y cuando abras N programas, éstos se distribuyan en los distintos núcleos disponibles.

Esto permitía un entorno multitarea real, asociado a múltiples recursos físicos, pero cada programa quedaba asignado a un núcleo. En ese sentido, programas muy demandantes de CPU corrían igual hubiera 1 o 4 núcleos en el sistema, lo cual era desaprovechar recursos.

Finalmente, con la masificacion de los procesadores multinúcleo, el software también evolucionó, y hoy en día es común que un mismo software genere distintos hilos (threads) de manera de correr simultáneamente en varios núcleos. Este enfoque combina el concepto de multiprocesador con multihilo (multithreading) y es la combinación que tienen todos los computadores de escritorio que vemos hoy en día.

---

**raya para la suma**

Windows 95 es multitarea, pero no soporta más de un núcleo ni más de un procesador. Windows 2000 en cambio, incorporó el multiproceso al ya existente soporte multitarea. Por lo tanto, sí existieron sistemas multitarea que no eran multiproceso.

Answer (score 2):

> entiendo que sí, que un sistema operativo multitarea tiene que ser a la fuerza multiproceso pero no lo entiendo. Si alguien me lo confirmara y me lo explicara, se lo agradecería. Saludos!!

No creo que sea **"a la fuerza"** sino que más bien al un sistema tener la cualidad de ser multitarea le permite también tener la bondad de ser multiproceso debido a que un sistema **multitarea** se refiere a aquel que es capaz de ejecutar varias operaciones **"simultáneamente"** como navegar por internet y reproducir música al mismo tiempo por ejemplo.

Al poder realizar de esta forma varias actividades esto le otorga al sistema la capacidad de ser **multiproceso** cuyo termino hace referencia a poder ejecutar varios procesos a la vez

> ¿Un sistema operativo multitarea tiene que ser también multiproceso?

En conclusión sí pero como te mencioné no **"tiene que ser"** sino que ya cuando hablamos en la actualidad de que un sistema es **"multitarea"** viene implicito que también es **multiproceso**. Es más importante el termino multiproceso porque es el que "engloba" el concepto de multitarea.

Tienes más información disponible en el artículo [Multiproceso, multitarea y multiusuario](https://sisoperativoutp2587.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/multiproceso-multitarea-y-multiusuario/).